# Создать простой http server в папке

Tags: css, python, http

Я пробую сохранять изменения в CSS на свой компьютер, чтобы после перезагрузки веб странице изменения остались.

В туториале на developers.google.com сказано:

"Start a local web server in ~/Desktop/app. Below is some sample code for starting up SimpleHTTPServer, but you can use whatever server you prefer."

```
cd ~/Desktop/app
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Итак, я пользуюсь IDE PyCharm, как через него выполнить эту команду я не знаю, хоть и установил `SimpleHTTPServer`

В командной строке в нужной папке при выполнении вышеуказанной команды я получаю

```
no module named SimpleHTTPServer
```

При выполнении команды

```
pip install SimpleHTTPServer
```

ошибка

```
Collecting SimpleHTTPServer
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SimpleHTTPServer (from
 versions: )
No matching distribution found for SimpleHTTPServer
```

Вопрос, как выполнить то, что предлагает google, может быть установить другой модуль для http server, а лучше как сделать это через IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какая версия питона у вас запускается по команде python?
Если третья, то в ней SimpleHTTPServer объединён с модулем `http.server` и запускать нужно так:

```
python -m http.server
```

Ну, или как вариант, явно запускать второй питон, если он у вас установлен:

```
python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Если туториал, которому вы следуете, был сделан под второй питон, то, возможно, именно эту версию и стоит использовать, чтобы не натыкаться время от времени на мелкие нестыковки между второй и третьей версией языка. Ну или поискать более свежий туториал :)